# Error on same place Trying to get property of non-object WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a function that returns an array of Custom Post type taxonomies:

```
function arfolio_get_cpt_tax(){

    $categories = get_terms( 'service_categories' );
    $cat_array = array();

    foreach( $categories as $cat ){
        $cat_array[$cat->term_id] = $cat->name;
    }

    return $cat_array;

}
```

I call this function in page.php. It's working fine. But When I am calling this function another file which is included in functions.php It's getting me error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in wordpress\wp-content\themes\arfolio-wp\inc\cpt.php on line 127
```

Please help me to fix this error.

The line 127 is in the above function:

```
$cat_array[$cat->term_id] = $cat->name;
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you including that file after this function ?

Comment: @Rikesh Yes, I am sure I am including the file after this function.

Comment: what is the line code in this line "cpt.php on line 127"  ?

Comment: @Reda $cat_array[$cat->term_id] = $cat->name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `$categories` is an array of object, to show it, put the following code:

```
function arfolio_get_cpt_tax(){

    $categories = get_terms( 'service_categories' );

    // See the var
    var_dump($categories); die();

    $cat_array = array();

    foreach( $categories as $cat ){
        $cat_array[$cat->term_id] = $cat->name;
    }

    return $cat_array;

}
```

It should shows you an objects array, if not, check what is the answer of the function, maybe is an array of arrays, and you should use something like:

```
function arfolio_get_cpt_tax(){

    $categories = get_terms( 'service_categories' );
    $cat_array = array();

    foreach( $categories as $cat ){
        $cat_array[ $cat['term_id'] ] = $cat['name'];
    }

    return $cat_array;

}
```

Comment: The above ( first ) gave me this result: `object(WP_Error)#111 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } } `

Comment: then you are quering wrong taxonomy .. chek your taxonomy name and try it

Comment: If I am quering wrong taxonomy, why it's working fine in `page.php`?

Comment: I `var_dump()` my function just before the place where I am calling this, it shows me this result: `array(1) { [""]=> NULL } `

Comment: Your problem is you're not checking what is returned, @anstrangel0ver points out, first, make sure you're giving back right results. When it'll be right should be something like (array) => [0] (object) 'term_id' => 12, 'name' => 'name', [1] (object) 'term_id' => 22, 'name' => 'name2' (Just written from heart, check the answer it's more or less like that)

Comment: you're not retrieving right values, that the problem

Answer (score 0):

`get_terms` return `WP_Error` object if it did not success please do

```
var_dump($categories); die();
```

and check the error 
it may be something like this

```
object(WP_Error)[196]
  public 'errors' => 
    array (size=1)
      'invalid_taxonomy' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Invalid taxonomy' (length=16)
  public 'error_data' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

if so please check that your taxonomy is exist

**Edit**

it's a case of your term fetching occurring before the taxonomy has been registered.

please check that you call your function after the that the taxonomy is registered
for example check that you include your file which calling the function is included after the registration of the taxonomy

I assume that you registered your taxonomy in the init action and the init action is called actually after the functions.php is included so any call of your function inside functions.php will not work 
so you need to use this function inside templates or in template parts

Comment: taxonomy is exist, because the function I posted in my question is working good in `page.php`